# Optional decimal with jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Tags: jquery, mask

I am trying to implement a mask using jQuery-Mask-Plugin 
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#field-options

From the doc this will allow me a recursive number with two decimal points.

```
 $('#test').mask("#,##0.00", {reverse: true});
```

But as the user starts typing 100 is being masked to 1.00 vs. 100
I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do this recursiveness from left to right as in, only if the user types '.' the decimal will be considered

For example

```
100 -> 100
1000 -> 1,000
1000.00 -> 1,000.00
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: any solution for that. I need same requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $('#test').mask("#,##0.00", {reverse: false});
```

reverse = false will allow you to type from right to left and you can leave decimal

Answer (score 0):

It works in my similary case

```
$('#test').mask('###,###,###,###P00', {
            reverse: true, 'translation': {
                P: {pattern: /\./, optional: true}
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var doptions = {
    reverse: true,
    translation: {
        'D': {
            pattern: /\./,
            optional: true,
            fallback: '.'
        }
    },
    onKeyPress: function (cep, e, field, options) {
        var masks = ['#,##0D', '#,##0D99'];
        var mask = (cep.indexOf('.') >= 1) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
        $('.money').mask(mask, options);
    }
};
$('.money').mask('#,##0D', doptions);
```